# Viewからidの中身をControllerにおくる方法

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Viewからリンクをクリックした時に、idの中身をContorollerで比較して先頭の文字によって処理をかえたいのですが、Viewからどのようにidを取得するのかが出来なかったので教えてください。
下記でいうとid="a_listItem.Id"のa_listItem.IdをContolloerで取得したいです。
お願いします。

view.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("IndexAjaxModal", "InformationList", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "resultAjaxModal" }, new { name = "formAjaxModal" })){<input type="submit" hidden="hidden" name="submitAjaxModal" />@Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.SelectedInformation.Id, new { id = "idAjaxModal", type = "hidden" })


 @foreach (var item in Model.ZentaiList.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index }))
    {
        var listItem = item.Value;
        <tr>
            <th>@item.Index</th>
            <th>@listItem.TourokuNichizi</th>
            <th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="modal-open" data-target="con" id="a_@listItem.Id">ListItem.Title</a>
        </tr>

    }

}
```

```
    @section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        //クリック
        $('.modal-open').click(function () {
            //
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            ajax_modal(id);


            var modal_id = $(this).attr('data-target');
            $('.tr_hide').css({ display: 'none' });


            modal_open(modal_id);
        });
    });
```

Controller.cs

```
 public ActionResult IndexAjaxModal(InformationListIndexModel model )
    {
     if(○○..StartsWith())
       {
        }
    }
```

Comment: `<a href="#">`となっているためJavaScriptの処理しか行われないと思いますが、どのように`IndexAjaxModal`アクションが呼び出されているのでしょうか。

Comment: すみません。取得したいのは、targetではなくてidでした。
javascriptでリンクをクリックしたときに、モーダルを開くようにしています。モーダルを開く毎にデータをdbから取得しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.SelectedInformation.Id, new { id = "idAjaxModal", type = "hidden" })
> ```

この値を設定したいということでしょうか？

**通常は**ヘルパーメソッドで生成される要素の`id`は`Html.IdFor`で求められますので、ビューのレンダリング時に`<script>`タグの中でヘルパーメソッドを使用しておけばJavaScriptから使用可能になります。たとえば`jQuery`であれば

$('#@Html.IdFor(e => e.SelectedInformation.Id)').val(id);

のように記述すれば

$('#SelectedInformation_Id').val(id);

が出力され、クリックイベントの発生時に`id`が反映されます。ただ**質問のコードでは`id`を変更されている**ので単純に

$('#idAjaxModal').val(id);

とすればよいです。

なお`<input type="hidden" />`を出力したい場合は`TextBoxFor`ではなく`HiddenFor`を使用してください。

Comment: pgrhoさん、ありがとうございます。